# How do I programmatically locate my Google Drive folder using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

Similar question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660280/how-do-i-programmatically-locate-my-dropbox-folder-using-c?rq=1). Just for `Google Drive` instead of `Dropbox`:

How do I programmatically locate my `Google Drive` folder using C#?

- Registry?
- Environment Variable?
- Etc...

Comment: I want to allow the user to select "Google Drive" instead of the C:\Users\XY\Google Drive\ as parent folder during the installation of my software. I searched the registry and AppData. There is a sync_config.db in %APPDATA%\Local\Google\Drive, but i don't know how to handle this.

Comment: Have you tried using the Google Drive API? https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart

Comment: HAve you had a look here: https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet

Comment: I assumed that the Google Drive API can be used to access, modify, upload etc. files on the remote servers. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I personally think, the best way is to access the same file through SQLite3.

```
string dbFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Google\\Drive\\sync_config.db");
if (!File.Exists(dbFilePath))
    dbFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Google\\Drive\\user_default\\sync_config.db");

string csGdrive = @"Data Source="+ dbFilePath + ";Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;";                
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(csGdrive);
con.Open();
SQLiteCommand sqLitecmd = new SQLiteCommand(con);

//To retrieve the folder use the following command text
sqLitecmd.CommandText = "select * from data where entry_key='local_sync_root_path'";

SQLiteDataReader reader = sqLitecmd.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
//String retrieved is in the format "\\?\<path>" that's why I have used Substring function to extract the path alone.
Console.WriteLine("Google Drive Folder: " + reader["data_value"].ToString().Substring(4));
con.Dispose();
```

You can get the SQLite library for .Net from [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki).
Also add reference to **`System.Data.SQLite`** and include it in your project to run the above code.

To retrieve the user, relpace **`entry_key='user_email'`** from the above code

Answer (score 6):

I took Sarath's answer, reworked it to be more resilient (quotes around data source path, null conditional on the reader indexing, additional error checking, "using" so objects are disposed appropriately, added a bunch of comments, and threw in some LINQ (because, linq :-) ).

This particular implementation catches and logs exceptions, and then returns string.Empty on any error...because that's how my current app needs it. Remove the try/catch if your app wants exceptions.

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieves the local Google Drive directory, if any.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Directory, or string.Empty if it can't be found</returns>
public static string GetGoogleDriveDirectory()
{
    try
    {
        // Google Drive's sync database can be in a couple different locations. Go find it. 
        string appDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
        string dbName = "sync_config.db";
        var pathsToTry = new[] { @"Google\Drive\" + dbName, @"Google\Drive\user_default\"+ dbName };

        string syncDbPath = (from p in pathsToTry
                            where File.Exists(Path.Combine(appDataPath, p))
                            select Path.Combine(appDataPath, p))
                            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (syncDbPath == null)
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Cannot find Google Drive sync database", dbName);

        // Build the connection and sql command
        string conString = string.Format(@"Data Source='{0}';Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;", syncDbPath);
        using (var con = new SQLiteConnection(conString))
        using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand("select * from data where entry_key='local_sync_root_path'", con))
        {
            // Open the connection and execute the command
            con.Open();
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();

            // Extract the data from the reader
            string path = reader["data_value"]?.ToString();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
                throw new InvalidDataException("Cannot read 'local_sync_root_path' from Google Drive configuration db");

            // By default, the path will be prefixed with "\\?\" (unless another app has explicitly changed it).
            // \\?\ indicates to Win32 that the filename may be longer than MAX_PATH (see MSDN). 
            // Parts of .NET (e.g. the File class) don't handle this very well, so remove this prefix.
            if (path.StartsWith(@"\\?\"))
                path = path.Substring(@"\\?\".Length);

            return path;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.TraceError("Cannot determine Google Drive location. Error {0} - {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```