# How do I programmatically locate my MEGAsync folder?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, megasync

Using C#, I want to locate the local root folder where MEGAsync syncronizes into.

There are several similar questions for other clould providers:

- [How do I programmatically locate my Dropbox folder using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9660280/107625)
- [How do I programmatically locate my Google Drive folder using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12173077/107625)
- [How do I find the OneDrive (SkyDrive) and GoogleDrive folders without the API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13454508/107625)

Still for MEGAsync I found no solution.

**My question:**

Is there any chance to find the MEGAsync folder without additional libraries?

**Update 1:**

There is a configuration file located at

> C:\Users\*MyUser*\AppData\Local\Mega Limited\MEGAsync\MEGAsync.cfg

All the content seems to be encrypted. So I doubt that there is any solution at all.

Comment: Would the "without additional libraries" include those from MEGAsync?

Comment: @BerndLinde Go ahead, I'll take whatever I can get :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and I figured out that the `MEGAsync.cfg` file that you mention in your question is actually not encrypted, each entry is just encoded as [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).  The format of each line is:

`<key>=<base64_encoded_value>`

You can decode each entry in the config file using C#'s ["Base64"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx) decoder, although I have only tested it with python.

Comment: This is no longer the case, I fear.
Looks like the settings are currently encrypted and *then* encoded as base64.