# Get local dropbox account info c#

Tags: c#, dropbox

I have dropbox installed in my Windows 7 system. Is there any way to programmatically retrieve the user email linked with the local dropbox account? I am able to retrieve the folder location by scanning the host.db file in local application directory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ! you can programmatically retrieve the user email linked with the local dropbox account with the help of "/account/info".

/account/info

- DESCRIPTION : Retrieves information about the user's account.
- URL STRUCTURE: https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/account/info
- METHOD : GET
- PARAMETERS: locale - Use to specify language settings for user error messages and   other language specific text. See the notes above for more information about supported locales.
- RETURNS : User account information.

  Sample JSON response
  {
      "uid": 12345678,
      "display_name": "John User",
      "name_details": {
          "familiar_name": "John",
          "given_name": "John",
          "surname": "User"
      },
      "referral_link": "https://www.dropbox.com/referrals/r1a2n3d4m5s6t7",
      "country": "US",
      "locale": "en",
      "email": "john@example.com",
      "email_verified": false,
      "is_paired": false,
      "team": {
          "name": "Acme Inc.",
          "team_id": "dbtid:1234abcd"
      },
      "quota_info": {
          "shared": 253738410565,
          "quota": 107374182400000,
          "normal": 680031877871
      }
  }

Return value definitions

field                        description

- uid   :                        The user's unique Dropbox ID.
- display_name    :          The user's display name.
- name_details/given_name   :    The user's given name.
- name_details/surname    :  The user's surname.
- name_details/familiar_name  : The locale-dependent familiar name for the user.
- referral_link     :        The user's referral link.
- country            :          The user's two-letter country code, if available.
- locale             :           Locale preference set by the user (e.g. en-us).
- email              :       The user's email address.
- email_verified        :        If true, the user's email address has been verified to belong to that user.
- is_paired          :       If true, there is a paired account associated with this user.
- team               :       If the user belongs to a team, contains team information. Otherwise, null.
- team/name           :      The name of the team the user belongs to.
- eam/team_id         :      The ID of the team the user belongs to.
  quota_info/normal           The user's used quota outside of shared folders (bytes).
- quota_info/shared    :     The user's used quota in shared folders (bytes). If the user belongs to a team, this includes all usage contributed to the team's quota outside of the user's own used quota (bytes).
- quota_info/quota      :    The user's total quota allocation (bytes). If the user belongs to a team, the team's total quota allocation (bytes).

Comment: I don't want to use any rest api's here as I want the account info from windows machine, that is the user account configured in dropbox application installed in windows

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173077/how-do-i-programmatically-locate-my-google-drive-folder-using-c/