# Determine Google Drive location with Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt, google-drive-api

Essentially this is a Qt/C++ variant of the question here :

[How do I programmatically locate my Google Drive folder using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173077/how-do-i-programmatically-locate-my-google-drive-folder-using-c)

What I have tried so far is given below

```
    QString gDrivePath =  QDesktopServices::storageLocation(QDesktopServices::DataLocation);
    gDrivePath += "\\Google\\Drive\\sync_config.db";
    bool result = QFile::copy(gDrivePath, "gdrive.db");

    QFile gdrivefile("gdrive.db");
    if(!gdrivefile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
        QMessageBox::information(0, "Google Drive path read error", gdrivefile.errorString());
    }

    QTextStream gin(&gdrivefile);
    gin.setCodec("ASCII");
    while(!gin.atEnd()) {
        qDebug() << gin.readLine().toLocal8Bit();
    }
    gdrivefile.close();
```

Like given in the question linked to above, the code makes a copy of the db file and tries to read it line by line. The only problem being that it is skipping a chunk of data from the file which contains the required "local_sync_root_pathvalue"

Any ideas ?

Comment: Wait a minute, you're reading a `sqlite` database as if it was a text file? That doesn't make any sense. The answer that gave you that idea is insane.

Comment: I see. The answer that I was following in the thread has been since deleted. And I could see the values when the file is opened with a text editor, so I tried to go with a quick fix.

Comment: It was a bad answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using sql classes from qt to achieve the feat.

Code:

```
    QString gDrivePath =  QDesktopServices::storageLocation(QDesktopServices::DataLocation);
    gDrivePath += "\\Google\\Drive\\sync_config.db";
    QFile::copy(gDrivePath, "gdrive.db");

    QFile gDriveFile("gdrive.db");
    if(!gDriveFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        qDebug() << "Error in opening Google Drive File" << gDriveFile.errorString();
    }
    else {
        QSqlDatabase gDrivedb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
        gDrivedb.setDatabaseName("gdrive.db");
        if (gDrivedb.open()) {
            QSqlQuery query(gDrivedb);
            if (query.exec("select * from data where entry_key='local_sync_root_path'")) {
                 while (query.next()) {
                     QString gDrivePath = query.value(2).toString().remove(0,4);
                     qDebug() << "Google Drive at - " << gDrivePath;
                 }
            } else {
                qDebug() << "Error in querying Google Drive db" << query.lastError();
            }
        }
        else
            qDebug() << "Error in Opening  Google Drive db";
        gDriveFile.close();
    }
```

Comment: Don't make a copy of the file, it's not only not necessary, but it can result in a corrupted copy if google drive happens to be modifying the file while you make a copy.

Comment: Well, you're right. That copy operation is unnecessary and indeterministic. Also followed from the deleted answer. I have tested the code without the copy and it works fine. Thanks @KubaOber

Comment: the first line does not work : `storageLocation' is not a member of 'qdesktopservices'`