# How to configure Qt to use SQLite?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I am very new to Qt and as well as Qt with database. Hope I get a positive response from you end.

I am using the code written in [this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649631/determine-google-drive-location-with-qt-c) for finding the Google drive folder path.

I made a successful progress till building by solving all the errors. The build was successful, But while running I get the following error

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: 
Error in Opening  Google Drive db
```

I know I missing somewhere the configuration of SQLite with Qt.
I just updated the pro file with `Qt += sql`

I can find the folders `C:\Qt\4.8.5.x64\src\3rdparty\sqlite`, `C:\Qt\4.8.5.x64\src\plugins\sqldrivers\sqlite`      in my system.

How to make the `QSqlDatabase` to link to this folder?
Or is there any separate installation for SQLite need to done for this or the libraries provided by the Qt itself is enough to support the database operation.

I have googled a lot, but didn't get any answers. Please let me know the steps to configure the SQLite.

Comment: The error relates to MYSQL driver. Are you sure you are using SQLITE database with QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE") ?

Comment: QSqlDatabase: QSQLITE driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: 
Error in Opening  Google Drive db
Yes... Sorry to upload the wrong output...

Comment: Do you start the exe in release or debug? Exists the gdrive.db in your folder?

Comment: I am running the exe in debug mode. Yes the file does exists in that folder

Comment: Can you tell me the output of:  qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers();

Comment: @Matthias It is giving an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `C:\Qt\4.8.5.x64\plugins\sqldrivers` do you see there `qsqlite4.dll`?

If not, than you should compile Qt with parameter `-plugin-sql-sqlite` if it static build, and compile qsqlite plugin manually if it shared.

```
cd %QTDIR%\src\plugins\sqldrivers\sqlite.pro
nmake
nmake install
nmake clean
```

Comment: [IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/ke6639.png[/IMG] Please find the snapshot of the sqldrivers folder. The qsqlite4.dll does exist.

Comment: Nice, so give me answer, you compiled Qt statically or shared?

Comment: To build a driver plugin you need to have the appropriate client library for your Database Management System (DBMS).  This is the statement I got it from Qt website... I should have a seperate installation done for SQLite rite? I thought since the Qt is providing all the libraries may be that suffice to work with it... Am i correct?

Comment: Why you didn't answer my question?  
Your qsqlite plugin is already builded in dll.  
If you are on static build, you should use Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(qsqlite) after QApplication.

Comment: I am really not aware of static compiling or shared compiling. I am just building and running the programs using Qt Creator.

Comment: What command line you have used to compile Qt x64?
If you have QtCore*.dll file in bin folder, than you are on shared build.

Comment: yes I do have the QtCore*.dll files in the bin folder.

Comment: Looks like Qt builded incorrectly.  
Have you compiled Qt yourself?  
If yes, than give me command line.  
If no, than you should compile it correctly or download from qt-project.org