# How do I programmatically locate my Google Drive folder in OSX?

Tags: macos, google-drive-api

Similar question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173077/how-do-i-programmatically-locate-my-google-drive-folder-using-c), but for OSX.
How can I programmatically detect the Google Drive path on OSX.
Couldn't find `sync_config.db` as in the Windows version.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, db file in OSX is located under:
`~/Library/Application Support/Google/Drive/user_default/sync_config.db`