# Saving to Dropbox folder using C# and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dropbox

I have an MVC 4 application that generates Excel spreadsheets from a template stored on my shared hosting FTP, but I would like the generated files to be stored in the user's Dropbox folder, not the server. How can I accomplish this using C#?

My files are currently saved as follows:

```
ExcelPackage p = new ExcelPackage(tempFile);

string newpath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content"), "Invoice.xlsx");
            FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(newpath);
            p.SaveAs(newFile);
```

`tempFile` is the template, which isn't relevant here. This code stores it on the server which I don't want.

Comment: You'll need to take a look at the [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) to see how to get access to a users dropbox account to upload it from the server on their behalf.

Comment: This answer here seems to indicate what you want: 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/9660541/1448512

Comment: @LorcanO'Neill Your link is not suitable to a web application

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using the [DropBox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers).

Unfortunately there is no official API for .Net, but you can find some on the Web like:

- [SharpBox](http://sharpbox.codeplex.com/)
- [DropNet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/DropNet)

I let you check how they work and determine which one is more appropriate to your project, but by looking at the [DropBox PHP API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php) it doesn't seem very difficult. It is based on HTTP and OAuth.

Comment: All I want to do is get the location of the dropbox folder on the user's computer, not write directly to the cloud folder.

Comment: You cannot access to the user's local folders for security reasons, but you can get locations inside the Dropbox folder. If your users are in your company you can create a local script, but not on the Web.

Answer (score 0):

You will not have any C# code running on the client in a web application and very doubtful you'd get the permission in any web application.  What you'd might want to consider is offer the user to download the file, suggesting they put it in their dropbox folder.

Comment: I may have not explained correctly, see I need to get the users dropbox folder on his/her computer. That way I just save the document to that folder and it gets uploaded automatically.

Comment: @barnacle.m you will not have the permission to access their local folder.  at best you could ask users to provide their dropbox credentials and you could use the dropbox api to write to their cloud which would then obviously sync to their local folder.