# CSIDL constant for dropbox folder in windows

Tags: windows, dropbox

I have installed Dropbox application in my PC which automatically installs a Dropbox folder in my hard drive, the location of Dropbox folder can be changed during installation. Now, to find the location of the Dropbox folder, i tried using SHGetFolderPath function which requires a CSIDL constant. How can i get the CSIDL constant for this folder?

Comment: Hi, maybe this one helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9660541/342594
It doesn't use SHGetFolderPath, but it gives you the location of the folder.

Answer (score 1):

The path is stored within JSON file in one of two possible locations:

- `%APPDATA%\Dropbox\info.json`
- `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Dropbox\info.json`

Read more on the official website:
https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/locate-dropbox-folder#programmatically