# How to get Dropbox directory using VBA?

Tags: vba, dropbox

Dropbox for Teams are doing an upgrade on December 10, 2022

As part of the upgrade, the directory of Dropbox will be changed from **Dropbox (me)** to **me (Dropbox)**.

This is part of the email we received.

> The Dropbox folder name will change from “Dropbox [team name]” to
> “[Team name] Dropbox.” You may need to modify any third-party
> automation file paths that are using the old Dropbox folder name for
> them to work properly after the upgrade.

At the moment we hard-code the dropbox file path in our VBA code

```
fromPath = "C:\Dropbox (me)\Development\" + aDir + "\"
```

Is there are a way of replacing this with code that will work both before and after the change.

For instance

```
fromPath = getDropBoxPath()+"\Development\" + aDir + "\"
```

Comment: You can try to check if dropbox stores the path it uses in the registry. To do that, open the Registry Editor, press Ctrl+f and in the search field, enter the path it currently uses. I don't have dropbox on my machine, so I can not tell you where to look exactly, but it might be `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SyncEngines\Providers\...`. Once you have found where the path is stored, you can use VBA to read that information from the registry. For a good example of how this can be done for example for OneDrive, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72736924/12287457).

Comment: Alternatively, you can check if Dropbox adds its working directory to your environment variables, which can be accessed using VBA. Use the following one-liner to print your environment variables to the immediate window: `Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To 50: Debug.Print Environ(i): Next i`. This will print a list of `%Key%=%Val%` to your immediate window. If the DropBox path appears there, you can access it using `Environ(%key%)`.

Comment: Thanks @GWD for your great ideas. I checked the environment variables, both on my computer and a colleague's, and it appears Dropbox does not add its working directory to the environment variables. I also looked in the registry - I found OneDrive in the place you mention, but I could not find Dropbox anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will do what I want. It is based upon @Reinaldo's answer in [How do I programmatically locate my Dropbox folder using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660280/how-do-i-programmatically-locate-my-dropbox-folder-using-c).

```
Function getDropboxPath()
  jsonPath = Environ$("LocalAppData") + "\Dropbox\info.json"
  Open jsonPath For Input As #1
    Input #1, firstLine
    aSplit = Split(firstLine, Chr(34) + "path" + Chr(34) + ":")
  Close #1
  getDropboxPath = aSplit(1)
End Function
```

I know the code can be improved but this is probably enough for me at the moment.

It uses the `info.json` file provided by dropbox and relies on the first line of the .json file being something like this.

```
{"business": {"path": "C:\\Dropbox (me)"
```

Comment: Very nice solution! I was thinking about also suggesting looking into the `LocalAppData` folder but decided not to since I don't have Dropbox and couldn't check where it dumps it's settings files. Regarding your solution: be careful when hard coding the file number as `#1`, if the calling code is already doing file IO with `#1` this will throw an error. Better would be to use the [`FreeFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/freefile-function) function to find a free file number.